# First ViewController from Tabbar cover the safe area(Status bar)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, statusbar, tabbar

After sucessful signin i am opening `Tabbar` with follwing code

```
    let  mainView = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabbar = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tabbar") as? Tabbar
    tabbar?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(tabbar!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Its open `Tabbar` with first index selected but first `ViewController` also cover the save area ...

[image]

and switching between the `TabbarItems` make it work fine ...

[image]

I am not able to understand why this happening only in one `ViewController` on first time open ... and how to tackle that.

Also tried following code but did't work ...

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Comment: try to present from main thread

Comment: Have a look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129610/pushing-a-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-13-causes-it-to-overlap-status-bar).

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro kind of same case ... but i created project on `Xcode11.5` and run on `iOS 13.5` ... and it's by default  generated the all code given in that answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Its not the proper solution its a kind of hack ... I told in Question that its get automatically fixed after switching between `TabbarItems` ... so i just added Two lines right after opening `Tabbar` VC.

```
       tabbar?.selectedIndex = 1
       tabbar?.selectedIndex = 0
```

And know the complete code seems like this.

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

```
     let mainView = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
     let tabbar = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tabbar") as? Tabbar
     appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
     appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = tabbar
     appDelegate.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
     tabbar?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
     self.present(tabbar!, animated: true, completion: nil)
     tabbar?.selectedIndex = 1
     tabbar?.selectedIndex = 0
```